# Set error button when i enter repeated invalid email or blank entry in subscribe form in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have been created subscribe form using php and jquery and sql to store data.

Now it is working fine, but it has some limitation.

When i enter invalid email address, it shows like this,

[image]

But i need to remove that message, i need only working effects with error button.

And If i enter blank, that time error button working fine[that is button will be shaken and says error], after that i enter valid address, it also working fine[that is success button].

One more think, if i enter invalid address at first, and second also enter invalid address,, the error button works fine at first time only.

Here is lib.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#newsletter').submit(function () { 
        var $this = $(this), 
        $response = $('#response'), 
        $mail = $('#signup-email'), 
        testmail = /^[^0-9][A-z0-9._%+-]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[@][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[.][A-z]{2,4}$/, 
        hasError = false; 

        $response.find('p').remove(); 

        if (!testmail.test($mail.val())) {
            $('#actbtn').removeClass('btn-error').addClass('btn-error');
            //$response.html('<p class="error">Please enter a valid email</p>'); 
            hasError = true; 
        } 

        if (hasError === false) { 
            $response.find('p').remove(); 
            $response.addClass('loading'); 

            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST", 
                dataType: 'json', 
                cache: false, 
                url: $this.attr('action'), 
                data: $this.serialize(),
                success: function(data){
                    if(data!=''){
                        $response.removeClass('loading'); 
                        if(data.status == 'success'){
                            $('#actbtn').removeClass('btn-error').addClass('btn-success');
                        }
                        else{
                            $('#actbtn').removeClass('btn-error').addClass('btn-error');
                        }
                    }
                }           
            });
        } 

        return false; 
    }); 
});
```

html:

```
        <div id="newsletterform">
            <div class="wrap">
                <h3>Get Email Update</h3>
                <form action="send.php" method="post" id="newsletter" name="newsletter">
                    <input type="email" name="signup-email" id="signup-email" value="" placeholder="Insert email here" />
<button id="actbtn" class="btn btn-7 btn-7h icon-envelope">Submit form</button>
                    <span class="arrow"></span>
                </form>
                <div id="response"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

May i know,how to achieve this one, Any idea would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi what you want to do now?

Comment: If you read well my posted question? @KarthikN . thanks

Comment: yes "But i need to remove that message, i need only working effects with error button" explain this

Comment: that is,  when i enter subscribe button with invalid email like text as input, it shows like this posted image(please enter an email address),, so i need to remove that marked one,,

Comment: so you want to remove "please enter an email address" am I correct? @rish

Comment: yes.. @KarthikN: and also have to correct some other mistakes.. let we know step by step..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72199/discussion-between-karthik-n-and-rish).

Comment: Duplicate of your own previous question, [Set jquery button instead of php error and success status](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28830327/set-jquery-button-instead-of-php-error-and-success-status) – if you have something to add to that, then do so by editing your original question, not by creating a new one.

Comment: okay @CBroe: thanks...here i removed only unexpected code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the

```
<input type="email" name="signup-email" id="signup-email" value="" placeholder="Insert email here" />
```

try to use it as input text because you did the script validation

```
<input type="text" name="signup-email" id="signup-email" value="" placeholder="Insert email here" />
```

Comment: That is rather bad advice, since it will cancel any additional behavior that the user agent might have in stock for `email` input fields (such as f.e. providing a list of email addresses set in the user profile to chose from).